# Highlighting text in Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, input-field

Is there a way to highlight text entered in the field using `sendKey()` in Selenium WebDriver in Java?

My code:

```
public static WebDriver driver, high;
    public static void highlight(WebDriver driver, WebElement ele) {
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('style', 'background: grey; border: 2px solid yellow;');", ele);
    }
        public static void highlight1(WebDriver high, WebElement ele1) {    
        JavascriptExecutor js1 = (JavascriptExecutor) high;
        js1.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('style', 'background: blue; border: 2px solid yellow;');", ele1);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException  {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/home/sharukh/Downloads/chromedriverv80/chromedriver");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5,TimeUnit.SECONDS) ;
        driver.get("https://www.mariatash.com/");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//div/div/button[@type='button'])[9]")).click();

        driver.findElement(By.id("sign_in_label")).click();

        WebElement username = driver.findElement(By.id("username-login"));
        highlight(driver,username);
        username.sendKeys("shahrukhsufiyaan@HIPPO.COM");

        WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.id("passwd-login"));
        highlight1(high,password);
        password.sendKeys("QWERTY");
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the below function

```
public static void highlight(WebDriver driver,WebElement element) {
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('style', 'background: yellow; border: 2px solid red;');", element);
}
```

Where driver is your `WebDriver` instance and `element` is the WebElement which is to be highlighted.

**Sample Code to make google search**

```
package test.cloudblm.com;

import java.io.File;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class maingoogle {

    public static WebDriver driver;
    public static void highlight(WebDriver driver,WebElement element) {
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('style', 'background: yellow; border: 2px solid red;');", element);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                new File("yourdriverpath").getAbsolutePath());
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/?safe=active&ssui=on");
        WebElement searchbar=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name=\"q\"]"));
        highlight(driver,searchbar);
        searchbar.sendKeys("QA is fun");


    }

}
```

Will highlight as shown in image below

[image]

Comment: how to use two highlight colors for a different elements.

Comment: i have added my code as answer.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try:

```
elem.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL,"a");
```

Output

[image]

**And about your code:**

It is failing because you are passing

```
  WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.id("passwd-login"));
  highlight1(high,password);
```

Instead of

```
  WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.id("passwd-login"));
  highlight1(driver,password);
```

**Highlighted output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

THIS IS MY CODE. IN THIS I AM HIGHLIGHTING USERNAME, PASSWORD FIELD.

```
public static WebDriver driver, high;
    public static void highlight(WebDriver driver, WebElement ele) {
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('style', 'background: grey; border: 2px solid yellow;');", ele);
    }
        public static void highlight1(WebDriver high, WebElement ele1) {    
        JavascriptExecutor js1 = (JavascriptExecutor) high;
        js1.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('style', 'background: blue; border: 2px solid yellow;');", ele1);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException  {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/home/sharukh/Downloads/chromedriverv80/chromedriver");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5,TimeUnit.SECONDS) ;
        driver.get("https://www.mariatash.com/");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//div/div/button[@type='button'])[9]")).click();

        driver.findElement(By.id("sign_in_label")).click();

        WebElement username = driver.findElement(By.id("username-login"));
        highlight(driver,username);
        username.sendKeys("shahrukhsufiyaan@HIPPO.COM");

        WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.id("passwd-login"));
        highlight1(high,password);
        password.sendKeys("QWERTY");
```